# WooCommerce added to cart message notification text

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been struggling all day to figure out how to add HTML content to the WooCommerce "added to cart" notification message. Per default it just displays plain text.
FYI - the actual text is translated in the WooCommerce .po file, to look like this:

```
<h5>added</h5><strong>%s</strong> has been added to your basket.
```

I have figured out to use the below snippet to convert the output to HTML, but I cannot figure out how to add it to the child theme functions.php

```
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

I am able to use it in this context, but would prefer to just pull the text from the .po file:

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'custom_add_to_cart_message' );
function custom_add_to_cart_message() {
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $message = '<h5>added</h5>Product has been added to your basket.' ; 
    return $message;
}
```

My php knowledge is at a bare minimum and I would really appreciate some feedback on how to implement the basic html changing code - add_filter / add_action or something similar.

Comment: Could you please check this - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237601/woocommerce-added-to-cart-message-on-mainhome-page

Comment: Thanks, I have read the thread before, but I cannot see how it can help me ? @Dmitry

Answer (score 1):

You can try code below:

```
function custom_add_to_cart_message() {
    $return_to  = get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('shop'));

    if (get_option('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')=='yes') {
        $message = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button">%s</a> %s', get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('cart')), __('View Cart &rarr;', 'woocommerce'), __('Product successfully added to your cart.', 'woocommerce') );
    } else {
        $message = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button">%s</a> %s', $return_to, __('Continue Shopping &rarr;', 'woocommerce'), __('Product successfully <h5>added</h5>to your cart.', 'woocommerce') );
    }

    return $message;
}
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'custom_add_to_cart_message' );
```

I checked it's work fine for me. Hope help you.

Comment: Thanks, but it does more or less (actually much more) than the last piece of code in my question. Is it not possible just to add the "content-type" code snippet and use the translated text ?

Comment: I was referring to my initial question. I would REALLY just prefer using the translated .po text (I am using another language than English), but the specific woocommerce message cannot output HTML (the error message can). Is it not possible to just change the output text to HTML ? Thanks again !

Comment: I had thought that it was a small thing and pretty easy to change the notification output text to HTML, but after spending most of the day, trying to figure it out, I've opted to keep it simple and go with the plain text version. Thanks for your input, @Dmitry, I believe the code works fine !